# Hide button in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am a little stuck and can't seem to work this out from the apple docs.

I have two buttons in an NSTable column, contained within an NSTableCellView.

I am trying to, in code, hide the button depending on the values of the object in the row.

Getting the values is fine, but i can't work out how to target the specific button, i can't bind it to an outlet as it's within a table. I have tried the below code, but that just hides the entire NSTableCellView rather than the specific button, i have also tried changing the identifier to be of the button, but that seems to do the same.

```
   if(selectedTweet.imageURL){

        NSButton *imageButton = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"secondButtons" owner:self];
        [imageButton setHidden:NO];
        return imageButton;

    } else {

        NSButton *imageButton = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"secondButtons" owner:self];
        [imageButton setHidden:YES];
        return imageButton;

    }
```

This is obviously much simpler than i am making it?? Help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Gareth

Comment: From your code I see your are trying to create a NSTableCellView with the button visible/hidden depending on the conditional.Have you tried  to have two different pre defined NSTableCellView on IB, like "secondButtonsWithButton" and "secondButtonsWithoutButton" and call each when necessary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CocoaBindings to populate that table, you can just bind the button's "Hidden" attribute to `Table Cell View/objectValue.imageURL` and use the `NSIsNil` value transformer. No code needed at all.

If you are using an old-fashioned data source, things become a tad more complicated. In that case you could have a imageButton property in your object, and set it in the NSTableViewDelegate's `- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row` method.

Comment: Holy cow dung, that is so super simple, thankyou so much, has also solved some other issues i was having. LEGEND!